# How to record cell position (not empty) and run macro for each of them

Tags: excel, vba

[image]    [image]

Hi everyone, I've not been able to write up anything as described in title after researching around the internet for abit. But, is there a way to record the cell position (not sure if I'm describing it correctly) of those cells which are not empty/blank, then to run a macro **ONLY** for each of those cell; **regardless whether they have been shifted or not?** For example (as per screenshot), if A1, A3 and A5 is not blank, then run marco only for these cells EVEN **if some of them are shifted to A4 or A8 later on.** So in short, I really need the macro to run only on these **cell IF it is not blank/empty.**

Comment: Just to add on, the inputs like **hello 1, hello 2, hello 3** will always be in the same column; but could be different row later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the raw structure of the code you are looking for. Adapt it to your project as you see fit and expand its functionality as you require.

```
Sub SkipBlanks()

    Dim Rl As Long                      ' last row
    Dim Tmp As Variant
    Dim R As Long                       ' row counter

    With Worksheets("Sheet1")           ' modify to suit
        Rl = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ' work on column A
        For R = 2 To Rl                 ' start the loop in row 2
            Tmp = .Cells(R, "A").Value
            If Len(Tmp) Then
                MsgBox "Cell " & Cells(R, "A").Address(0, 0) & _
                       " has the value """ & Tmp & """.", _
                       vbInformation, "Test report"
            End If
        Next R
    End With
End Sub
```

For a quick test, add two or 3 values in random places of column A and run the code.

Comment: Thanks Variatus! Let me work on this set of codes now.

Comment: Hey Variatus, I tried to edit onto your set of codes, somehow it just perform macro on the first cell that is not blank. Perhaps its clearer to show you what i'm trying to do. This is my initial input (https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6UdX.png), and I've already got a working macro to split a cell into several rows below it. However, right now, it isn't doing the same(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAKvM.png) for A6 and A9 after performing the task for A1. I'm sorry in advance if this is all confusing for you.

Comment: Your problem is in the adaptation, not the code. Best way, create a sub `Main`. From that sub first call your existing sub that splits the rows. Then call the sub that I gave you. If you seek to delete empty rows must work from bottom up. If none of this works ask a new question in which you post your code and the problem it's giving you.

Comment: Hi Variatus, thanks for the prompt reply! I will work around with your suggestion first. If all else fail (pardon me for being a newbie),I will then raise another post again for this. Thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: Hello again @Variatus! I've managed to get your code working to what I wanted (right adaption). However, onto your set of codes, probably just a tweak, how do I make `R1` not a constant (not a fixed value). So is it possible to update it after every iteration right before `Next R`.